# Clojure custom function for threading macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I have a map and I want to write a custom function for updating it.

```
(-> {:a 1 :b 2}
    (fn [x] (update x :a inc)))
```

This of course is a simple example and could be easily done without the function wrapped around the `update`, but it shows what I want to do. But this gives me the following error.

```
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/fn at (core.clj:108:1).
{:a 1, :b 2} - failed: vector? at: [:fn-tail :arity-1 :params] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list
{:a 1, :b 2} - failed: (or (nil? %) (sequential? %)) at: [:fn-tail :arity-n] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body
```

I don't get why this is not working, since the threading macro should but my map as first parameter in the function, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use [`macroexpand`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand) to see what happened.  In your case, macroexpand will return you:

```clj
(fn {:a 1, :b 2} [x] (update x :a inc))
```

obviously this is not a valid function.  But if you tweak it this way:

```clj
(-> {:a 1 :b 2}
    (#(update % :a inc)))
```

the expanded form will then become valid:

```clj
(#(update % :a inc) {:a 1, :b 2})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't put a function itself to be called, but call the function without the first parameter, For your example it would be:

```
> (-> {:a 1 :b 2} 
      (update :a inc))

{:a 2, :b 2}
```

This is easier to see by expanding the macro in each case

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {:a 1 :b 2} (update :a inc)))

(update {:a 1, :b 2} :a inc)

> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {:a 1 :b 2} (fn [x] (update x :a inc))))

(fn {:a 1, :b 2} [x] (update x :a inc))
```

Comment: I didn't want to use `update` but something else this was just for demonstration. So the code doesn't really solve the problem. Anyways this showed me where the issue was. I was giving the macro a function, where it cannot insert the parameter. So I need to wrap my function into extra parentheses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @jas and @rmcv pointed out, I was giving the threading macro the function itself, not the call of a function without the argument. So in short terms the solution would be

```
(-> {:a 1 :b 2}
    ((fn [x] (update x :a inc))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of these solutions are the simplest.  I would propose choosing one of the following:

---

A. Use the normal threading form:

```
(-> {:a 1, :b 2} 
  (update :a inc))   => {:a 2, :b 2}
```

Everyone is used to seeing this and can understand it easily.  Since you have already rejected this approach, I assume you think the code is clearer by using a named parameter.

---

B. Use a named function

```
(defn updater [x] (update x :a inc))

(-> {:a 1, :b 2} 
    updater)         => {:a 2, :b 2} 

(-> {:a 1, :b 2} 
    (updater))       => {:a 2, :b 2}
```

This is more how the `->` form was envisioned to work.  I think the 2nd version is the clearest, as it is the most consistent where all function expressions have parentheses (single arg or multi-arg).

---

C. Consider using the `it->` macro from [the Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro):

```
(it-> {:a 1, :b 2} 
      (update it :a inc))   => {:a 2, :b 2}
```

Much like the named function, the expression is normal Clojure form without the "invisible" parameter silently inserted into the `update` expression.  The pronoun `it` serves as the temporary placeholder for the threaded value (an idea copied from Groovy).  Simple, explicit, and flexible, since the `it` can be in the first, last, or any other parameter location:

```
(it-> 1
      (inc it)                                  ; thread-first or thread-last
      (+ it 3)                                  ; thread-first
      (/ 10 it)                                 ; thread-last
      (str "We need to order " it " items." )   ; middle of 3 arguments
;=> "We need to order 2 items." )
```